# To get Matlab's Save Path by Java/Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab

I am trying to install [WFDB](https://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/) Toolbox system-unspecifically in my systems (Ubuntu Linux 64bt/OS X El Capitan/Windows 10 education). I need to get the Matlab Path i.e. set in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/toolbox/local/pathdef.m` by Java/Matlab own means. However, I did not find an approach for that. 
Pseudocode

```
matlabpath=char(java.lang.System.getProperty('user.path'));
```

where I tried in *path* also *matlabpath*.

I have specific locations where I keep sufficient permissions for Matlab. 
I need the approach i.e. user.path such that I know where I need to keep sufficient privileges. 
Warning that I get when installing WFDB in Ubuntu Linux 64 bit and Matlab 2016a, which is a complication of not being able to manage the path non-system-specifically

```
Warning: Unable to save path to file '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/toolbox/local/pathdef.m'. You
can save your path to a different location by calling SAVEPATH with an input argument that
specifies the full path. For MATLAB to use that path in future sessions, save the path to
'pathdef.m' in your MATLAB startup folder. 
> In savepath (line 169)
```

Java would be the best solution for this, but Matlab's own solution is ok too.

---

How can you get Matlab's path by Java/Matlab?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the path set within MATLAB or the system PATH?

Comment: @Suever Matlab calls this `pathdef.m` in the indicated position. I want to get the path system-unspecifically such that I can install the toolbox system-unspecifically. I updated the body.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What path do you want to get? From the error message it seems the installation root is already found.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it is found in Unix system. However, I want to know how you can find the thing in all systems such that you can set it in all systems.

Comment: For such problems there is typically no platform independent solution, for what operating systems do you search a solution?

Comment: @Masi Wait, so the issue is that WFDB wants to edit the path but doesn't have permission to do so? What does this have anything to do with the "user.path". Also please define what you expect "user.path" to be.

Comment: @Suever I offer you an explanation in the body. I need to know the user.path non-system-specifically in order to solve the issue.

Comment: @Masi It's still not super clear, but check out my answer below, I would probably just do everything with `userpath`. Let me know if that suits your needs.

Comment: The question is unclear. What path do you try to identify on what operating systems?

Comment: @Daniel I answered your questions in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "MATLAB Startup Folder" can mean many things depending upon the user's configuration as well as the operating system.

The Mathworks has a whole page about this [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/matlab-startup-folder.html).

One way is to ensure that the startup folder is the same as the [`userpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/userpath.html) (how you do this depends on your OS so see the link above). Then you can access that from within MATLAB using the `userpath` command.

```
folder = userpath
```

If you're on Linux, you can ensure that the `userpath` is used as the Startup Folder by following this excerpt from the link above.

> Default Folder on Linux Platforms
>
> On Linux® platforms, the default startup folder is the folder from which you started MATLAB.
>
> To specify the userpath as the startup folder, set the value of the environment variable MATLAB_USE_USERWORK to 1 before startup. By default, userpath is userhome/Documents/MATLAB, and MATLAB automatically adds the userpath folder to the top of the search path upon startup. To specify a different folder for userpath, and for other options, use the MATLAB userpath function.

There is another option (on newer versions of MATLAB) that would allow the user to set their startup path to whatever they want and you still be able to determine it.

Since R2014b, users can specify the initial working path in the preferences (**MATLAB General** -> **Initial Working Folder**). You can check if the user has specified a custom initial working directory using the following commands

```
settings = Settings;
folder = settings.matlab.workingfolder.InitialWorkingFolder;
```

**Disclaimer**: This functionality was discovered by looking at MATLAB's own `matlabrc` file and while there is *some* documentation for `Settings` it's likely not officially supported, so use at your own risk.

Comment: I think this will do. I will let you know if I notice any warnings/errors later.